# Invalid api call happen during get stock price

Tags: stock

{    "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED."}

why its came ? what is the reason

I want to get stack price using TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED or TIME_SERIES_DAILY but getting this issue

Comment: What language are you using (please tag your post accordingly)? What code did you run (please post it)?